# Can someone explain in simple terms Cassandra nodetool commands like compact and cleanup?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

**Hello Everyone**

I am new in databases and i am trying to understand some Cassandra commands. I would like to know about the following commands :

- nodetool compact
- nodetool cleanup
- nodetool repair
- nodetool garbagecollect

I would appreciate some simple and clear answers like -> nodetool help : it shows all the commands and their usage.

> The problem i am trying to solve is that after i delete (a lot of data) the storage is still full. I change the gc_grace_seconds to 1 day and still nothing. So if i need to clear the space manualy right now which commands should i run and in what order?

*Thanks for your time*

Comment: what about using Cassandra documentation? https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/nodetool/nodetool.html

Comment: Hey Alex,
I have already check the documentation and of course i searched around the web but i did not find the answers i want.... for example i can not understand the difference between cleanup and compact and when to use them etc. ( I dont want just to try different commands and say hmm this one works so this is right)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Erick! Thanks a lot i did not knew about that... i think that https://dba.stackexchange.com/ just became my new daily search.